# Game slows down when key pressed (hardware keyboard)

Tags: android, event-handling, keyboard

In my game when I press any button game slows down. I don't think, that it is associated with my event handlers, situated in main thread (which is UI thread - this is normal to Android) Maybe there is something, I must set in configuration or some properties. Build target is Android 2.1. I'm testing on XPERIA X10 mini pro. One more thing: game isn't slowing down, when I run it on emulator on a better PC.

Comment: Does the slowdown exist if all handlers are removed?

Comment: code? Definitely sounds like an event handler problem to me.